# how to connect to redislab using nodejs(ioredis) and why this error occuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis, ioredis

at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
errno: -3004,
code: 'EAI_FAIL',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'redis:123.redislabs.com:18094'
}

how to connect with redis lab in nodejs using ioredis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a malformed Redis URL and not a hostname to me. If your using a URL to connect to Redis is should be like this:

```
redis://123.rediabs.com:18094
```

Hope this helps.